# What is the significance of '-client' for JAVA_OPTS

Tags: client, significance, java-opts

I am not an expert on JAVA_OPTS, but I am getting an error in my grails app related to Permgen space. Now I receive a recommendation from grails blog to set JAVA_OPTS to this value:

JAVA_OPTS="-client -Xmx256M $JAVA_OPTS"

I do understand the other values except '-client'. What does it really mean? I can't find the significance of it in books.

Answer (score 2):

The `-client` and `-server` options are intended to optimize performance for client and server applications; the default varies by platform, where typically client-oriented platforms (Windows, MacOS) get the client VM by default, and typically server-oriented platforms (Linux, Windows Server) get the server VM by default. More information is available here: http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/vm/index.html

Basically, the client VM is optimized to start up quickly and use less memory, while the server VM is designed for maximum performance after start-up.

Answer (score 1):

Usually, there is `-server` and `-client`,
`-client` starts faster than `-server`.

Nowadays, in some versions, like AMD64 version, it does nothing, there is only server version.